# Migrating from Spring Boot Microservices Project to Serverless using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices, serverless, aws-serverless

I have created a Spring cloud microservices project with netflix APIs and a frontend with React. Now, I want to migrate this project to serverless using amazon web services with DynamoDB and cognito. Do you know, which steps should I follow to do that? And what should I consider before doing this migration? For the Frontend React I decided to use S3 to host it.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure if u really want to do this . This will be a big project; almost like re-writing complete codebase. Good part is that lambda supports Java so u might end up doing lots of copy paste. You would have a lambda function of each REST api endpoint u were exposing.